# my vcproj does not comiple when added in another sln (already containing some other project)

Tags: compilation, solution, pango, vcproj

I have pangoft2.vcproj. Once I have set the include directories etc., it compiles successfully.

Now, in a new .sln (where I have a pango.vcproj), I add this pangoft2.vcproj. Now, when I compile the program, it gives 474 errors. 
I have copied a few lines here:

---

Error   20  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_g_utf8_skip thai-shaper.obj

Error   47  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol g_utf8_get_char   thai-shaper.obj

Error   121 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol pango_glyph_string_set_size   thai-shaper.obj

Error   130 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol pango_font_get_glyph_extents  thai-shaper.obj

---

I must tell you that I have included the required libraries (pango-1.0.lib and glib-2.0.lib) in the project.

Can you tell me the possible reason of this error and how to over come it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the error.

The project was in the Debug x64 mode, when I should have used debug win32 mode.